# How can I make the mouse cursor render with software instead of hardware?

Tags: windows, windows-8, mouse, cursor, f.lux

I use a program called f.lux to change the display color. However, the color does not affect the mouse: leaving it an ugly bright white. A partial fix is to set the registry value of mouse trails to -1, but this causes some games to be unable to render the cursor whatsoever, due to incompatibilities with pointer trails (making them useless).

I am looking for a method to completely disable the hardware cursor. I know some games can do it, but I cannot find anything for Windows itself. Is there a different setting I could change to force hardware acceleration, or a script I could write? Or, is there a way to change registry settings for just some programs (the games that don't support pointer trails)?

Comment: Why not look for a mouse cursor theme that matches your colour scheme?

Comment: I could try, but I'd probably have to design it myself. In addition, I have f.lux cycling through different levels throughout the day, so it would look different at sunset vs. midnight. That's the plan if I can't find a better way, though.

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3436/how-to-apply-color-management-to-the-windows-7-mouse-cursor

Comment: @Richie I found that in my search, but there was no other OS based fix besides mouse trails.

Comment: change the color of the display using the video card's color management instead of windows' color management, or change it on the monitor?

Comment: Use colors in the curser instead of white, works best when creating crosshair cursers instead of lame pointers. Or just get most of the white out, and use the white only for highlighting instead of its overall colorations.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of enabling pointer trails for f.lux, try switching to the **inverted** cursor set.

If you can get used to its oldschool design, it solves all problems:

- color management is applied
- works in most games
- cursor does not "scream" at you